# shared folder in vhosts

Tags: php, server, plesk

I just migrated to a new server using centos and plesk. I have uploaded my files into  /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs. The httpdocs has all of my website files. I have also added shared libraries into /var/www/vhosts/secured/libraries/.

However if i try and require  the libraries i get a blank page regardless of the error_reporting setting. If i test using `is_file` or `is_dir` on the same required location i get false. what am i doing wrong. i am using php

thanks

Comment: have you tried require with the full path?

Comment: pretty sure thats the full path i am using it as such dirname(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]))

Comment: how about: `require('/var/www/vhosts/secured/libraries/file.php');`

Comment: returns false or nothing

Comment: then the files are not where you think they are\or the permissions are wrong and php has no access to them

Comment: Right but i have filezilla open and i can see it in that exact dir. I am new to plesk and am thinking that the files are somewhere else and i just have no clue where to look

Comment: whats the file\directory permissions?

Comment: i gave it full access 777

Comment: well i'm out of ideas.

Comment: its frustrating - makes me want to ditch plesk

Comment: if i use file_exist(dirname(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]))."/website")
 i get true however if i use file_exist (dirname(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]))) i get false im sooooooo lost

Comment: using server variables when you dont know the issue makes the debugging so much harder

Comment: dirname(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]))  = "/var/www/vhosts/"

Comment: Essentially the website folder exists but its parent folder does not